# Insulator behavior of large U limit in Hubbard model

Tags: quantum-spin, phase-transition, many-body, insulators, strong-correlated

I am now learning the many-body physics and having some questions about the insulator behavior of large $U$ limit for the Hubbard model :

\begin{equation}
H = -t\sum_{\left\langle {i,j} \right\rangle, \sigma}c^{\dagger}_{i,\sigma}c^{}_{j,\sigma} + U\sum_{i}n_{i,\uparrow}n_{i,\downarrow}.
\end{equation}

I already know that by assuming $\frac{U}{t} >> 1$ and the half-filling limit the energy spectrum of the system will have a **charge gap** with order $\approx U$.

But if we only consider the behavior for the group of lowest energy states (namely below the charge gap), we can perturbatively obtain the effective low energy Hamiltonian as

\begin{equation}
H \approx \frac{4t^2}{U} \sum_{\left\langle {i,j} \right\rangle} {\bf S}_{i} \cdot {\bf S}_{j}
\end{equation}
which is the so called Heisenberg antiferromagnet.

Also, the effective Hamiltonian describing the charge distribution gives one electron per site.

My question is as follow :

**1.**

The large $U$ limit of the Hubbard model is also called the **Mott insulator** because the electrons are now localized in each site of the lattice. Although it might seem trivial that the **localization** of the electron give rise to insulating behavior, I am wondering since there will be some low energy **spin excitation** corresponds to spin-1 magnon, is the system really a insulator? Given the fact that there are gapless excitations, I can not understand why it is a insulator. (although there is actually a large charge gap, we can still achieve a excitation by magnon)

**2.**

It is widely accepted that this diagram characterize the metal-Mott insulator transition :
[image]

However I can not understand why the density of state will be completely filled in the lower energy part of the splitting due to $e^{-}-e^{-}$ interaction. Is there any rigorous derivation to prove that these lower energy states (below the charge gap $U$) is completely filled to give an insulating state?

If I make some mistakes in the above reasoning please let me know :)

I would be extremely grateful for any suggestions on my questions!

Comment: In my limited understanding, your point of view on the first question is correct. Here the Mott insulator should be literally an insulator whose current-current correlator decays exponentially whereas spin-spin correlator does not. Thus this concept of an insulator is simply having zero electric conductivity, which does not exclude gaplessness.

Comment: Hubbard III paper discuss about your second question, I guess...